# python pythonpath modules

Tags: python, pythonpath

Ok a short question:

Is there any SIMPLE software with a GUI, that lets me manage my pythonpath, path python version in mac?

So I could set my Python, pythonpath and python version i want to use.

Thanks!

@ katrielalex and S.Lott :

I had a very nightmare with installing modules in python and as pointed out correctly in another question the reason is that I have a Mac with 2 Pythons installed:

One preinstalled by Apple in /usr/bin
One from python.org in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/x.y

So now every time I hit easy_install It installs it to Apples pre installed.

And I really came close to the solution, but now I figured out (again!) it wont work.

I just would like to have a simple solution. Where I can say:

1. Which is my main python I am using (.org or buildin). The one that if I run any code will be used.
2. Be able to tell easy_install where to install my modules (preferably in both, just in case)

Thats why a texteditor did not work for me until now.

And I really like python, but got really, really annoyed by dealing with that basic problem every time.

If you could tell me step-by-step explanation what I have to do to achieve this. This would be a great day in my year.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a niche market! If you're technically competent enough to know what a PYTHONPATH is, you should probably be able to Google how to set environment variables on OSX. It requires editing a text file.

http://adammechtley.com/2009/10/setting-up-your-pythonpath-environment-variable-globally-on-osx/

Comment: @MacPython: that is a different question, one which you have already asked and and for which you received an excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566546/python-pythonpath-modules-install =) The gist was that you need to use the right `easy-install`. This is not a configuration option; you are running *the wrong program*.