# Problems installing lxml on a Mac, it installs but module not found

Tags: python, macos, lxml

The code

```
from lxml import etree
```

produces the error

```
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Running

```
sudo easy_install lxml
```

results in

```
lxml 2.2.7 is already the active version in easy-install.pth 
Removing lxml-2.2.7-py2.5-macosx-10.3-i386.egg from site-packages and rerunning sudo easy_install lxml results in
Adding lxml 2.2.7 to easy-install.pth file
Installed /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/lxml-2.2.7-py2.5-macosx-10.3-i386.egg
Processing dependencies for lxml
Finished processing dependencies for lxml
```

And yet I still get No module named lxml

What step am I missing in order to use lxml on my Mac (OSX 10.5)?

*Update*

**python --version** reports

```
Python 2.5.2
```

and running python produces

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 22 2008, 07:57:53) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5363)] on darwin
```

Comment: As expected, that does not appear to be the Apple-supplied Python 2.5 in 10.5 (that is a Python 2.5.1).  Try `python -c 'import sys;print sys.executable'` to be sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to be trying to `easy_install` lxml into the Apple-supplied Python 2.5 for OS X 10.5 but using an egg that was likely built with a python.org Python 2.5.  If you have both installed on your system, keep in mind that you need to have a separate `easy_install` (setuptools or Distribute) for each Python.  Apple supplies one in `/usr/bin` for its Python.  Ensuring that you are using the python.org one (check `which python`), you should follow the installation instructions for setuptools or Distribute to install an `easy_install` for it.  That `easy_install` will be in the `bin` directory of the python.org framework:  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5//bin`.  Use that `easy_install` to install `lxml`; it should then automatically end up in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib`.  There is a more detailed discussion of a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566546/python-pythonpath-modules-install/3566965#3566965) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582715/python-install-uninstall-easy-install/3583477#3583477).

Comment: I have found your numerous posts on managing multiple Python versions on Mac OS to be invaluable in helping me navigate my own issues in that regard. My question is: when are you going publish the book that pulls all that wisdom together in one place? I would certainly buy a copy!

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad you find them to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple versions of python installed on your computer. `lxml` is installed for one, and you're invoking the other. There's not enough context to divine any more than that.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install-2.7 lxml`

Worked on Mac OS 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing is not right here.
The package being added is lxml-2.2.7-py2.5-macosx-10.3-i386.egg
It refers to mac os x 10.3 , while you are using mac os x 10.5.

Try python --version, what does that tell you?

Comment: The `10.3` in the file name refers to the ABI (`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`) of the Python instance used, not necessarily the OS X version you are running.  For example, traditionally python.org OS X installers are built with `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3` so that the same installer and Python can be used on OSX 10.3 and above (including 10.5 and 10.6).

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml
```

made it work
see http://lxml.de/build.html#building-lxml-on-macos-x